# Draw a finite automation for {w ∈ Σ ∗ | w does not contain the substring 10}

Tags: computability, regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions, computation-models

So I am trying to draw a finite automation that has no limits on the length, but cannot have the substring of `10`

I created a DFA that could satisfy this requirement, but am uncertain about the accept states having `01` because you can use the loop to create something like (i.e. 10**10**10).

[image]

But I can't add additional transitions from stage a like the picture below because you add too many zeros with the loop to get 00**10**000

[image]

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it required that your finite automaton accepts empty strings? The only requirement appears to be the non-occurrence of $10$. If so, $a$ must be an accepting state.

The idea is that whenever your finite automaton accepts a $1$, it cannot accept any more $0$s. The following DFA is my suggestion.

[image]

*Edit: I forgot to specify the initial state.*

Comment: But what about if the string ends in 0, such as 0110? It has 10 but that is at the end and not a substring

Comment: A suffix is a substring. It happens to be at the end. If $10$ being the suffix is acceptable (which I doubt the problem you are trying to solve allows), then when your FA is fed with a $1$, it can tolerate only one $0$ and nothing else. You can add a third state below $b$, called $c$. When the FA is fed $0$ in $b$, it transits to $c$ and does not accept any additional character.

Comment: Your automaton recognizes the empty language: there is no initial state.

Comment: @Nathaniel Indeed. Thank you for pointing out the oversight. I edited the post.